# EntityFramework Oracle C# - can't compare Timestamp with Datetime in where Clause

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, timestamp, entity-framework-6

I am using an Oracle Database and the Nuget Packages

- Oracle ManagedDataAccess v12.2.1100
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework v12.2.1100
- EntityFramework v6.0.0

In the Oracle Database there is a field defined with Timestamp(6).
As I am Using Database first, this gets converted into DateTime.
So far so good.

Now I am going to insert the current timestamp into the table:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
//only 3 parts of milisec
DateTime zeitStempel = dateTime.AddTicks(-1 * dateTime.Ticks % 10000);

using (Entities ctx = new Entities(DBConnect.BuildConnectionString(_bedien, "ModelJobLog")))
{
    JOB job = (from e in ctx.JOB
               where e.PROGNAME == progName
               select e).FirstOrDefault();

    JOBLAEUFE lauf = new JOBLAEUFE();
    lauf.JOBID = job.JOBID;
    lauf.JOB = job;
    lauf.LETZTSTART = zeitStempel;

    ctx.JOBLAEUFE.Add(lauf);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Everything is fine, in my Field i have the value:
"26.10.17 07:39:53,381000000"

Now i remember this dateTime (variable zeitStempel) and now i am going for a search for it in this table.
So i still have the same dateTime object and search now for the value in the Database and want to set the current dateTime in another field:

```
using (Entities ctx = new Entities(DBConnect.BuildConnectionString(_bedien, "ModelJobLog")))
{
    try
    {
        Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStamp tmstmp = zeitStempel;
        JOBLAEUFE lauf = (from e in ctx.JOBLAEUFE
                          join j in ctx.JOB on e.JOBID equals j.JOBID
                          where j.PROGNAME == progName
                          &&( e.LETZTSTART.Equals(zeitStempel)
                              || (e.LETZTSTART.Year == zeitStempel.Year
                              && e.LETZTSTART.Month == zeitStempel.Month
                              && e.LETZTSTART.Day == zeitStempel.Day
                              && e.LETZTSTART.Hour == zeitStempel.Hour
                              && e.LETZTSTART.Minute == zeitStempel.Minute
                              && e.LETZTSTART.Second == zeitStempel.Second
                              ))
                          select e).FirstOrDefault();

        lauf.LETZTEND = DateTime.Now;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

If I compare in the where clause *with* the Seconds i never get the value of the DB. If i however leave the Seconds out of the where clause, he finds the database record. But of course the minute alone is not precise enough.

Both, e.LETZTSTART and zeitStempel are from DateTime and if I check in debugging all properties are the same.

Kind regards,

Comment: Maybe try `Math.Truncate(e.LETZTSTART.Second) == Math.Truncate(zeitStempel.Second)`

Comment: Thanks for the input, .Second is already an integer, so no truncation needed.

Comment: Can you change data type in database to ` TIMESTAMP(0)`?

Comment: Changed it to timestamp(0) , still isn't working, the problems are still the seconds